# Add a bookmark in opened files and save them as dcox

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a question about bookmarks. I made a macro that deletes all the bookmarks in a Word document and adds a new bookmark:

```
Sub AddBookmarkInCurrentFile()
'
' Deletes all the bookmarks in an already opened file
' and add one new bookmark in the file
'
   ' Deletes al current bookmarks
     For Each bkm In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        bkm.Delete
     Next bkm

    ' Put Cursor add the beginning of the file and adds the bookmark
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:="testBookmarkAdd"

    MsgBox "Finished"
End Sub
```

When I run this it works fine.

Because I have to do this for more then 100 documents and save the *.doc as .docx I made a new version of the macro. Everything works accept the adding of the new bookmark. What is wrong in the code below?

```
Sub AddBookmarkInAllOpenedFiles()

' Opens all word files in a directory and deletes current bookmarks
' and adds one bookmark and saves the file to a docx file

    Dim sSourcePath As String
    Dim sTargetPath As String
    Dim sDocName As String
    Dim docCurDoc As Document
    Dim sNewDocName As String

    Dim sOrigName As String
    Dim intPos As Integer

    ' Looking in this path
    sSourcePath = "H:\Mijn Documenten\test\"
    sTargetPath = "H:\Mijn Documenten\test\Converted\"

   ' Look for first DOC file
    sDocName = Dir(sSourcePath & "*.doc")
    Do While sDocName <> ""
        ' Repeat as long as there are source files
         'Only work on files where right-most characters are ".doc"
        If Right(sDocName, 4) = ".doc" Then
            ' Open file
            Set docCurDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=sSourcePath & sDocName)


            ' Deletes all the bookmarks
            For Each bkm In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
                bkm.Delete
            Next bkm

            ' Put Cursor add the beginning of the file and adds the bookmark
            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
            ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:="testBookmarkAdd"

            'Saves the document as a docx
            sNewDocName = Replace(sDocName, ".doc", ".docx")

            With docCurDoc
                .SaveAs FileName:=sTargetPath & sNewDocName, _
                FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
                .Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
            End With
        End If
        ' Get next source file name
        sDocName = Dir
    Loop
    MsgBox "Finished"
End Sub
```

Comment: Avoid using `ActiveDocument`. This method refers to the document which is on top at the moment the code runs. This is not very reliable. Instead of `ActiveDocument` use  `docCurDoc` to refer to **exactly** that document that you opened with `docCurDoc = Documents.Open`.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
Sub BookmarkAllFilesInFolder()
' Opens all word files in a directory and deletes current bookmarks
' and adds one bookmark and saves the file to a docx file
Dim sSourcePath As String, sTargetPath As String
Dim sDocName As String, docCurDoc As Document

' Looking in this path
sSourcePath = "H:\Mijn Documenten\test\"
sTargetPath = sSourcePath & "Converted\"

' Look for first DOC file
sDocName = Dir(sSourcePath & "*.doc")
' Repeat as long as there are source files
Do While sDocName <> ""
' Only open .doc files"
  If Right(sDocName, 4) = ".doc" Then
  ' Open file
  Set docCurDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=sSourcePath & sDocName, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With docCurDoc
    'Delete all existing bookmarks
    While .Bookmarks.Count > 0
      .Bookmarks(1).Delete
    Wend
    'Add our bookmark
    .Bookmarks.Add Name:="TestBookmark", Range:=.Range(0, 0)
    'Save the file in .docx format to the output folder
    .SaveAs2 FileName:=sTargetPath & sDocName & "x", _
      FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault, AddToRecentFiles:=False
      .Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    End With
  End If
  ' Get next source file name
  sDocName = Dir
Loop
Set docCurDoc = Nothing
MsgBox "Finished"
End Sub
```

Comment: While code only answers might seem to help the OP they are bad practice. You should explain what you did/changed and why, so the OP and further readers can learn from it. Otherwise it is pretty useless in my eyes and you just did the OPs work (which is not the intend of Stack Overflow). Only adding some useful explaining content beyond the code makes it a good answer.

Comment: Yes, but how can he (or future readers) understand/learn if you don't explain which changes were made why? That's the point here.

Comment: So I understand what you did, and tried it. There weird thing is, that in some documents it works and other word documents it doesn't work. The templates I use it doesn't work but when I create a new Word document and use the code it does work. unfortunately I can't share the template document because it is company policy. The template I use has formfields and headers and footers. Is that the reason I doesn't work?

Comment: Well, it won't work in documents with any kind of protection applied (e.g. 'filling in forms' for formfields) unless you first remove that protection. That's a problem if the protection may or may not include a password that you may or may not know. It would have been helpful had you mentioned that as an issue up-front instead of leaving it till now.